# generating git commit info with rubber (for LaTeX, Debian)

Tags: debian, python, git, latex

I'm using the [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber) program (in Python, from Lauchpad) to process a LaTeX document (thru `pdflatex` called by `rubber -d`) on Debian/Sid/Linux (the document is some H2020 European R&D proposal). I have the version 1.4-2 of that `rubber` package.

The LaTeX document and its directory is versionned using [git](http://git-scm.com/).

I want to have a LaTeX command there which gives the current git commit id, to be able to show that id in the generated PDF file.

When I run the following shell command in my terminal :

```
printf '\\newcommand{\\cgitcommitid}{%s}\n' $(git log --format=oneline --abbrev=16 --abbrev-commit -q | cut '-d ' -f1 | head -1)
```

It gives me the expected output:

```
\newcommand{\cgitcommitid}{99ad2f058a5c06d8}
```

so I would like to generate that in some `cgit-gitcommitid.tex`  *generated* file.

I have the following `cgit-rubber-rules.ini` file:

```
; This is our extra rules cgit-rubber-rules.ini file for Rubber
; Rubber is a LaTeX driver in Python
; see https://launchpad.net/rubber

;; SVG figures produced by InkScape (see http://inkscape.org/ for more)
;; convert to PDF
[cgit-inkscape-svg-to-pdf]
target = (.*)\.pdf
source = \1.svg
cost = 4
rule = shell
command = inkscape --without-gui --export-pdf=$target $source

;; convert to EPS

[cgit-inkscape-svg-to-eps]
target = (.*)\.eps
source = \1.svg
cost = 4
rule = shell
command = inkscape --without-gui --export-eps=$target $source

[cgit-gitcommitid-make]
target = cgit-gitcommitid\.tex
;source = \.git
cost = 3
rule = shell
command = printf '\\newcommand{\\cgitcommitid}{%s}\n' $(git log --format=oneline --abbrev=16 --abbrev-commit -q | cut '-d ' -f1 | head -1) > cgit-gitcommitid.tex
```

My `cgitprop.tex` main LaTeX file has:

```
 % file cgitprop.tex
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{svg}
 \usepackage{ifpdf}
 \usepackage{wasysym}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{eurosym}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{relsize}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{alltt}
 \usepackage{marginnote}

 % rubber: module pdftex
 % rubber: module graphics
 % rubber: rules cgit-rubber-rules.ini

 % rubber: clean cgit-gitcommitid.tex
 % rubber: make cgit-gitcommitid.tex with cgit-gitcommitid-make from .git
 % rubber: watch cgit-gitcommitid.tex
 \input{cgit-gitcommitid}
```

But when I run  `rubber -v -v -d cgitprop` the `cgit-gitcommitid.tex` file is *not* generated:

```
   rubber -v -v -d cgitprop
  This is Rubber version 1.4.
  [latex] directive: module pdftex
  [latex] built-in module pdftex registered
  [latex] parsing /ssdhome/basile/CGIT2017FET/cgitprop.tex
  [latex] script module article registered
  [latex] built-in module graphicx registered
  [latex] directive: produce cgitprop.out cgitprop.brf
  [latex] directive: watch cgitprop.out
  [latex] script module hyperref registered
  [latex] directive: module pdftex
  [latex] directive: module graphics
  [latex] built-in module graphics registered
  [latex] directive: rules cgit-rubber-rules.ini
  [latex] directive: clean cgit-gitcommitid.tex
  [latex] directive: make cgit-gitcommitid.tex with cgit-gitcommitid-make from .git
  [latex] directive: watch cgit-gitcommitid.tex
```

and later

```
  [leaf] 'cgit-gitcommitid.tex' does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't `cgit-gitcommitid.tex` properly generated?
Uncommenting the `;source = \.git` line -by removing the initial semicolon- in my `cgit-rubber-rules.ini` file does not change anything.

Or do you know any LaTeX package available on Debian to generate the `git` information -the commit id-?

<sup>also asked on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/rubber/+question/425935) & [quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-to-use-%E2%80%98rubber%E2%80%99-utility-in-Python-for-LaTeX-to-generate-git-information-on-Debian)</sup>